# When to use "right" and when to use "correct" in a sentence?

Tags: word-choice

When should you use the word "right" in a sentence (ex. "Did I say your name right?") vs using the word "correct" (ex. "Did I say your name correctly?").  Is there a "rule" or an easy way of remembering which word to use?

Comment: I wouldn't use 'right', at least not in that context, because it is not adverbial. 'Correctly' is fine. You could perhaps say say 'Have I got the right name for you'.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you explain further when one should use either word?  I figure a lot has to do with the context, but I can't seem to find how to use which word and when...

Comment: One important thing is that if it is qualifying a verb it should be 'rightly' e.g 'I don't rightly know'. But if you say 'Have I got your right name?' right is being used as an adjective. Even so you would not say 'He did it rightly', 'correctly' would be much better. But you can say 'Am I right in thinking you are Charles Merton?' You really need to be on the English Language Learners site.